# Combine several attribute tables into a single Excel

Tags: qgis, export, excel

Is it possible in QGIS to combine several attribute tables into a single Excel? Unfortunately, I cannot find a suitable function/command. Copying and pasting all attribute tables individually is too time-consuming.

I have created different layers with "Extract position" that show which points are in the respective zones. My goal is to create an overview that shows which points are in which zones.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Merge Vector Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgismergevectorlayers) then [Export to spreadsheet](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/layertools.html#qgisexporttospreadsheet) tools.

[image]

[image]